sizeof char[]="some" is strange
char  string0[]=  "0123456789";  // sizeof(string0)=11
char  string1[11]="0123456789A"; // sizeof(string1)=11

The string1 case is clear, allocated 11 Bytes for chars plus one for '\0' and sizeof() do not count terminator.
The string0 case is not clear to me, allocated 10 Bytes for chars plus one for '\0', so sizeof() should report 10
Why sizeof() say the same size in both cases?

"allocated 10 Bytes for chars plus one for '\0'" that makes 11.

You should probably try sizeof("0123456789A") as well.

Because you told the compiler that the second one was sizeof() 11 when you wrote the line char  string1[11].

See also Behaviour of sizeof with string?

Note that string2 is not a string, since it lacks a null-terminator, making the name a bit misleading.

sizeof is not strlen(), don't use it to get the number of chars in a string. Also you don't need to put parenthesis with sizeof, it is not a function.

To make the comment by Joël more complete. sizeof is an operator and parentheses are not needed when applied to expressions (similar to the unary minus operator in this aspect), but it also has a special syntax for applying to a type directly like sizeof(int). In the latter case, the parenthesis is required.


sizeof() do not count terminator"

sizeof reports the size of the allocated memory. There is no counting involved. You might be mistaking sizeof for strlen, which indeed does not count the string terminator.
The first one is auto-allocated, and is size 11 because you have 10 characters and NUL. The second is manually allocated to size 11, which is filled with 11 characters, with no NUL since there is no space for it; if you try to print it (or indeed apply strlen on it), you will get gibberish at best.
See Why does gcc allow char array initialization with string literal larger than array?

Or perhaps more dangerously, since this is UB, printing it or calling strlen may work perfectly if the next byte in memory happens to be zero.

OK, than you all, now is clear.
I post some code to show this behave:
#include <stdio.h>

char  string0[];                 // space for '\0', initialized
char  string1[10];               // space for 10 Bytes, initialized
char  string2[10]="";            // space for 10 Bytes, initialized
char  string3[]="";              // space for '\0', initialized
char  string4[]=  "0123456789";  // space for 11 Bytes, 10 plus '\0'
char  string5[11]="0123456789A"; // space for 11 Bytes, 11 char, miss '\0'
char  string6[10]="0123456789";  // space for 10 Bytes, 10 char, miss '\0'
char* string7;                   // space for sizeof(ptr), not initialized
char* string8=NULL;              // space for sizeof(ptr), initialized to NULL
char* string9=string4;           // space for sizeof(ptr), initialized

//stringX; // same as &stringX[0]

int main() {
   printf("size:%02ld string0:'0123456789A'\n", sizeof("0123456789A")); // 12 '0123456789A'
   printf("size:%02ld string1:'%s'\n", sizeof(string1), string1);       // 10 ''
   printf("size:%02ld string2:'%s'\n", sizeof(string2), string2);       // 10 ''
   printf("size:%02ld string3:'%s'\n", sizeof(string3), string3);       //  1 ''
   printf("size:%02ld string4:'%s'\n", sizeof(string4), string4);       // 11 '0123456789'
   printf("size:%02ld string5:'%s'\n", sizeof(string5), string5);       // 11 '0123456789A'
   printf("size:%02ld string6:'%s'\n", sizeof(string6), string6);       // 10 '0123456789'
   printf("size:%02ld string7:'%s'\n", sizeof(string7), string7);       //  8 NULL
   printf("size:%02ld string8:'%s'\n", sizeof(string8), string8);       //  8 NULL
   printf("size:%02ld string9:'%s'\n", sizeof(string9), string9);       //  8 '0123456789'
   
   printf("string4[9] : %02d '%c'\n", string4[9] , string4[9]);  // '9'
   printf("string4[10]: %02d '%c'\n", string4[10], string4[10]); // ''
   
   printf("string5[9] : %02d '%c'\n", string5[9] , string5[9]);  // '9'
   printf("string5[10]: %02d '%c'\n", string5[10], string5[10]); // 'A'
   printf("string5[11]: %02d '%c'\n", *(string5+11), *(string5+11)); // '' confirm NULL
   printf("string5[12]: %02d '%c'\n", *(string5+12), *(string5+12)); // ''

   printf("string6[9] : %02d '%c'\n", string6[9] , string6[9]);  // '9'
   printf("string6[10]: %02d '%c'\n", *(string6+10), *(string6+10)); // '' confirm NULL
   printf("string6[11]: %02d '%c'\n", *(string6+11), *(string6+11)); // ''

   printf("string4 addr:%p\n", string4);
   printf("string5 addr:%p\n", string5);
   printf("string6 addr:%p\n", string6);
   return 0;
}

